# How to access the welcome NGINX page in a AWS Ubuntu instance from the internet browser?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I just created a new instance of a ubuntu 16.04. Just installed a NGINX and this is what I have after a `netstat -ntlp`

```
root@ip-172-31-8-234:/home/ubuntu# netstat -ntlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11856/nginx -g daem
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1328/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      11856/nginx -g daem
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1328/sshd
```

If I ask a  curl localhost that is what I get:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-8-234:~$ curl localhost
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the welcome NGINX page. So, it seems the NGINX is done.

But I would like to be able to see this page trough the internet.

This is what I have in my AWS servicies page.

```
Public DNS (IPv4) - ec2-54-94-152-233.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Instance state - running
IPv4 Public IP - 54.94.152.233
```

So I think I should be able to see welcome page if I woud type 54.94.152.233 in any browser.

Instead I get this error message:

```
This site can’t be reached

54.94.152.233 took too long to respond.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: your VPC/Security group settings might not be allowing packets through port 80

Comment: it worked good. I just added another rule http to port 80

Comment: cool, posted that as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default VPC & security group settings, far as I remember do not allow for any incoming traffic on any ports. Change the settings to allow incoming traffic on port 80 and you should be good